# Is it okay to put file URL decoded in jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm streaming music with 206 partial content on multiple requests (e.g. a 7 MB song will be served in 7 requests and 7 responses for each 1MB chunk size):

```js
const contentLength = end - start + 1;
  const headers = {
    'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}`,
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Length': contentLength,
    'Content-Type': contentTypeHeader,
  };

res.writeHead(206, headers);
const audioStream = fs.createReadStream(songPath, { start, end });
audioStream.pipe(res);
```

Two requirements of my system are:

1. The user streaming the music must be authenticated.
2. The user should not know the audio URL on the filesystem.

For this, I'm thinking of creating two routes:

1. First route will authenticate the user, and provide them with jwt with the audio file URL
2. Second route will accept that jwt, decode it, get the audio file URL, and stream it.

My question is, does decoding this jwt on every request for each chunk of audio take much toll on the CPU?

Or is there any better way for this?

Comment: Yes it will take much toll on the CPU, decoded `jwt `  can be cached

Comment: @Navitas28 could you give me some pointers on that?